# Design guidance for Mobile RSS Feed Reader

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile, rss, feed

I am working on a mobile (windows phone) RSS Feed Reader pet project.
I had a few design decisions on which I needed guidance. Here they are:

1. Firstly, when the feed reader downloads the RSS feed how can I show which items are read by  the user vs. those that are new or not-read. 
   Do I store the file contents locally in a DB along with the information of which articles are read/unread.

   2. Secondly, when we download the RSS feed, do we download the entire file? I guess even with an approach like CONDITIONAL-GET to fetch feed contents only on update, there is no way to download a delta of the RSS file.
   3. Thirdly, if the entire file is downloaded, do mobile feed readers show data from beginning or truncate it to show feeds only from last N days (where N is an integral number of days like 15 or 30)

Thanks in advance

Regards

Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building a mobile phone application, there are 2 ways you could go: either have a server keep track of the updated content and let the devices connect to it to retrieve it or handle everything (fetching, parsing and diffing the feeds) from the phones.

For your questions:

1. You have to keep track locally (on the device) of what the user has read or not. You'll probably use the `<guid>` or `<id>`(Atom) elements in feed's entries to identify each of them and keep track of lists of items that were read.
2. Conditional GETs (if-Modified-Since and ETag) will not help you very much because when the content has been updated, they serve you the *whole* RSS/Atom document. So, yes, you'll have to download the whole file over and over again, and yes, that's a lot of waste.
3. This is really up to you. It may actually be relatively "cheap" to store everything on the device and let the user decide if they want to delete the past stories.

If you don't want to deal with the hassle of fetching, parsing and diffing RSS feeds, I suggest you check services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which can do that on your behalf either on the server or on the device!